# Webpack 5 require JSON as `asset/resource` instead of `asset/source`

Tags: webpack, pug

I am trying to load a JSON file in my HTML (pug):

```
link(rel="manifest" href=require("/meta/webmanifest.json"))
```

But the href gets replaced with the contents of the JSON:

```html
<link rel="manifest" href="{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;...}">
```

I have `{test: /\.(ico|svg|png|ttf|json)$/, type:  "asset/resource"},` in my webpack config but this does not change the behavior for JSON. Is there any way around this?

(Using pug with pug-plugin)

Comment: Why are you using `require()` instead of just the path to the file?

Comment: the issue in pug-plugin will be fixed, follow the issue ticket on github